# How to retrieve data from method call by AJAX in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I have created class method in call `GetDatabase()` with following code:

```
 public string GetDatabase()
    {
        var db_holiday = dbObj.RetrieveData("SELECT Holiday_description, Date FROM ServiceReport.dbo.WS_Holidays");
        if (db_holiday != null)
        {
            var holiday_rows = db_holiday.Tables[0].Rows;
            List<string> des_holiday = new List<string>();
            List<string> des_date = new List<string>();

            foreach (DataRow row in holiday_rows)
            {
                var holiday = row["Holiday_description"].ToString();
                var date = row["Date"].ToString();
                des_holiday.Add(holiday);
                des_date.Add(date);
            }
        }
```

I've stored two databases into separated list which is `des_holday` and `des_date`.

In **ASP.net**:

```
<div class="container col-lg-2 bg-warning ">
    <div ID="week_display" class="m-grid-col-center">

    </div>
</div>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Test.aspx/GetDatabase",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

I'm currently using `.ajax()` to call back `GetDatabase()`.
**My main goal is to display all of my element inside the two list.**
I'm stuck right and don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you working on classic `asp.net` or `asp.net core MVC`?

Comment: I'm working with asp.net

Comment: You could set the `POST` annotations on the top of your `[web method]`, it should hit your method then return `json response`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. When the ajax is running, the success will run the OnSuccess function. By putting

```
    function OnSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data.d);
   }
```

Will obtain the data.